# Stream video from Pi to an OpenCV application on a local remote computer

Tags: opencv, c++, rtsp

I am working on a project which requires real time processing of frames in a video. I have Pi setup with a Picamera.

What I want is to stream video directly to an OpenCV application which is located on a computer in a local network.

How can I go about doing this with low latency?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `uv4l`.
`uv4l` easily implement camera control and webRTC streaming, in a very efficient way, and quite easily. So your RPi will stream the camera on the network, while the computer will acquire frames from the RPI via opencv videoCapture class, as if it was a classic video file or camera, in order to analyse them.

More information about uv4l here  : https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/